# How to display a list of tuples and count the same number of elements

Tags: python, list, tuples, namedtuple

**input**
 def inisial(daftar):

```
daftar = (

     "Michael","Viny","Aurelio","Michael",
     "Felix","Kevin","Vincen","Vincen","Michael")

inisial(daftar)
```

**output:**

Michael

Viny

Aurelio

Michael2

Felix

Kevin

Vincen2

Vincen3

Michael3

Comment: I tried to make the program but failed

Comment: You're question is too vague. What should the input be, and what should the output be? Please give an exact example.

Comment: the output is the name in tuple, if the name is more than 1 then the output will output example vincen 1, vincen 2

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to count the number of occurences for each name. If so, you can do it like this. If you want the output to be different you can, of course, change the return format of the dictionary.

```
def inisial(daftar):
    d = {}
    for daft in daftar:
        if daft not in d:
            d[daft] = 0
        else:
            d[daft] += 1

    return d

daftar = (

     "Michael","Viny","Aurelio","Michael",
     "Felix","Kevin","Vincen","Vincen","Michael")

inisial(daftar)
```

Output:

```
{'Michael': 2, 'Viny': 0, 'Aurelio': 0, 'Felix': 0, 'Kevin': 0, 'Vincen': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to count frequencies of entries in your list and use this frequencies in returend list.

```
def inisial(daftar):
    freqs = {}
    for name in daftar:
        freqs[name] = freqs.get('name', 0) + 1
    ret = []
    for name in daftar:
        freq = freqs[name]
        if freq == 1:
            ret.append(name)
        elif freq > 1:
            ret.append(name + str(freq))
    return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Sandertjunh's answer, you could use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=collections%20counter#collections.Counter).

Answer (score 0):

you can solve the problem with the following code.

```
daftar = ("Michael", "Viny", "Aurelio", "Michael",
          "Felix", "Kevin", "Vincen", "Vincen", "Michael")

temp_dict = {}
for name in daftar:
    if temp_dict.get(name):
        temp_dict[name] += 1
    else:
        temp_dict[name] = 1

    if temp_dict[name] > 1:
        print('%s%d' % (name, temp_dict[name]))
    else:
        print(name)
```